# Get data as Array and not as object - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get the data from table `tbl_devedor_parcela`, using the field `negociacao_id`, so I need to retrieve the data from table `tbl_devedor_parcela` as `array`. The first `ID` of the table `tbl_devedor_parcela`, is being retrieved as an `array`, but the others are being retrieved as an `object`.

[image]

How do I recover everything as an array?

Following tables;

***tbl_devedor_negociacao***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_devedor_negociacao`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_devedor_negociacao` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt_negociacao` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `atualizar` VARCHAR(5) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_finalizacao` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `contrato_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `crud` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

***tbl_devedor_parcela***

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_devedor_parcela`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_devedor_parcela` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dt_vencimento` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `num_parcela` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `valor` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `negociacao_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `atraso` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `crud` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

***Source Model***

```
//Excerpt from Source- Home
//Negotiations
$id_contratos = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}, $result['contratos']);
$negociacoes = $this->obter_negociacao($id_contratos);    

//Parcelas
$id_parcelas = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}, $negociacoes);
$parcelas = $this->obter_parcela($id_parcelas);

//view
$id_contratos = array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['id'];
}, $result['contratos']);
$empresa = "Banco Semear";
$view["empresa"] = $empresa;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result['contratos']); $i++) {
    $id = $result['contratos'][$i]['id'];
    $result['contratos'][$i]['view'] =
        array_filter($view, function($a) {
            return $a;
        });
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($negociacoes); $i++) {
    $id = $negociacoes[$i]['id'];
    $negociacoes[$i]['parcelas'] =
        array_filter($parcelas, function($a) use($id) {
            return $a['negociacao_id'] == $id;
        });
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result['contratos']); $i++) {
    $id = $result['contratos'][$i]['id'];
    $result['contratos'][$i]['negociacoes'] =
        array_filter($negociacoes, function($a) use($id) {
            return $a['contrato_id'] == $id;
        });
}

return $result;
//Excerpt from source - End

//get Negotiations
public function obter_negociacao($id) {
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_devedor_negociacao);
    $this->db->select("tbl_devedor_negociacao.*, IF(tbl_devedor_negociacao.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud", FALSE);
    if (is_array($id)) {
        $this->db->where_in('contrato_id', $id);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('contrato_id', $id);
    }
    $this->db-> order_by('contrato_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
//get parcela
public function obter_parcela($id) {
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_devedor_parcela);
    $this->db->select("tbl_devedor_parcela.*, IF(tbl_devedor_parcela.crud = 'C', 'R', 'C') as crud", FALSE);
    if (is_array($id)) {
        $this->db->where_in('negociacao_id', $id);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->where('negociacao_id', $id);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get('');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I got success with array_values***

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($negociacoes); $i++)
{ 
    $id = $negociacoes[$i]['id'];
    $negociacoes[$i]['parcelas'] =
       array_values(array_filter($parcelas, function($a) use($id)
       {
           return $a['negociacao_id'] == $id;
       }
   )); 
}
```

[answer here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252844/obter-dados-como-array-e-n%C3%A3o-como-objeto-codeigniter/253212#253212)